# What will be the t-value if my sample size increases to an infinity compare to z value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, sample-size, t-distribution

I do not know where to check this. Any reference/help is much appreciated.

If the sample size, `n` increases to an infinity then will the t-value be larger/smaller than the z-value at the same cumulative probability? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \rightarrow \infty$ the t distribution with converge towards the standard normal. You can of course prove that statement, but you could also just try calculating probabilities with your statistic software. I think in Excel $P(x  \leq a)$ (for the t distribution) will be equal to  the same as with the normal distribution, when n is around 70.000.

Another to see it, without a formal proof, is to look at the variance of t distribution: $ n/(n-2)$ for $n > 2$. Then for  $n = \infty$ this will be 1. Same as the standard normal.

Comment: will it be larger/smaller than the z-value? or almost equal to the z-value?

Comment: for $n = \infty$ they are the same. Otherwise it should be smaller, given that the tails are more fat.

Answer (score 0):

It gives same probability as standard normal distribution.

As For $n\to\infty$ , $t_n\to N(0,1)$